# Regex replace - Is there a better way to switch declaration and assignment

Tags: c#, regex, visual-studio-2010

I was looking for a way to switch my assignments i.e:

```
a = b;
```

becomes

```
b = a;
```

In case anyone is wondering, it's for loading settings and unloading them.

I crafted a regular expression for it:
Find what: `{[^:b]*} = {[^;]*}`
Replace with: `\2 = \1`

This works fine, but is there another way to load and save settings that I'm missing?

Comment: Consider: `a += b;` or `string s = "=";` or `/* = */`

Comment: Your solution sounds OK. Are you experiencing a specific problem?

Comment: @Bart This sort of thing was only for loading and unloading settings e.g. in Form.Load event pull the settings out of the .settings file and populate the form and in the btnSave.Click event, load the new settings from the form into the .settings file.

Comment: @Pieter I am not experiencing a problem, it was just a question of whether this is the easiest way to do it.

Comment: It just looks like what you're doing should work. You could make your regex a little bit more robust, like @Bart Kiers says, but that's it.

Comment: @Pieter, off topic: your link `http://cv.webathome.org` doesn't work (anymore). I *did* find it on `http://webathome.org/cv` though. You might want to get that fixed.

Comment: thanks all for the responses. i will just continue using the Regex as I have up until now.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach: what about making a settings class with a method that copies values? In that way you write the list of assignments only once:

```
using System;

class Settings {
    public int ValueA { get; set; }
    public string ValueB { get; set; }
    public void CopySettings(Settings other) {
        ValueA = other.ValueA;
        ValueB = other.ValueB;
    }
}

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        Settings a = new Settings() { ValueA = 3, ValueB = "something" };
        Settings b = new Settings();
        // and then you can do one the following, which will copy all settings
        // in both cases...
        b.CopySettings(a);
        a.CopySettings(b);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's more for the loading and saving of settings between the .settings file and the Form elements, as in my comment above. Thanks for the reply, but this is not really what I was asking.

Comment: @Joao: sorry, had not yet seen your comment when I posted this.